# how is binding a value to variable different than returning a value to variable?

Tags: rust, syntax

I was reading the Rust programming language manual,
let x = (let y = 6);
this produces an error cause: The let y = 6 statement does not return a value, so there isn’t anything
for x to bind to. This is different from what happens in other languages, such
as C and Ruby, where the assignment returns the value of the assignment. In
those languages, you can write x = y = 6 and have both x and y contain the
value 6 ; that is not the case in Rust.
what is difference between binding and returning a value?

let x = (let y = 6);
gives an error

Comment: _Binding_ and _returning a value_ are very different things. What is common to them?

Comment: And in C too, you cannot do `int x = (int y = 6);`.

Comment: `This is different from what happens in other languages, such as C` No it isn't. `int x = (int y = 6);` is just as invalid in C as it is in Rust.

Answer (score 0):

Initialized declarations are statements but not expressions; they look like assignments, but are not.  An initialized declaration is `let x = 1` but an assignment is `x = 1` (note the absence of `let`).

Rust is like other languages in that many syntactical constructs that are valid statements do not return a useful value, but Rust is different in that many constructs that are only valid in statement position in other languages can be used in expression position in Rust.  For example, you can assign the result of a loop, which is almost always `()` (the unit value, the closest thing Rust has to the concept of "void" from other languages).  More commonly, you see the result of an `if`/`else` chain bound to a variable.

Assignment expressions always produce the unit value `()`.  So you can do this:

```
let mut x;
let mut y;

x = y = 1;

println!("{:?} {:?}", x, y);
```

Like other languages, `y` will have an integral type and be assigned the value `1`.  Unlike other languages, `x` will have the type `()` and be assigned the value `()`!  The output of this program is:

```
() 1
```

> what is difference between binding and returning a value?

Binding is when you give a name to a value.  `let x = 1;` binds the value `1` to the name `x`.  `let foo = bar();` binds whatever value `bar()` returns to the name `foo`.

"Returning a value" happens from functions, but the more general concept of "evaluating to a value" happens with every expression-level construct in Rust, which includes blocks such as `if` and `loop`.